# Create user profiles on the android device like we have accounts on PC

Tags: android, android-widget, android-menu

Can we create an app on Android where we can create user profile on the device and when the device start (or powered on) then user selects an account and enter password. Based on the account user apps, settings etc is loaded. These profiles are same as we have accounts on my PC or laptop.

I just want to know weather is this possible on android or not?

Comment: The reason why it is not available yet is that mobile phones are personal devices and not multiuser. Although since mobile OS are also evolving and being used on tablets, android may by default support profiles in coming versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an open research question. There are some works where people try to separate different phone profiles, for instance, [this](http://l4android.org/).

The problem actually is the following. As you may know Android is built on top of Linux kernel. You also may know that Linux is multiuser system (you can have several separate accounts). But in case of Android there is only one actual user possible. Because Linux user's id are assigned to different applications. I.e. each application in Android is a separate user. This is done for the sake of security of applications (different applications in this case are run in separate virtual memory spaces and, thus, cannot influence on each other)